# Unable to overwrite bootstrap-sass's font with that of font-awesome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, font-awesome

I am using bootstrap-sass and the font-awesome ( https://github.com/littlebtc/font-awesome-sass-rails) gems. I would like to override the bootstrap font setting from that of font-awesome.

From font-awesome's site I can override the bootstrap defaults, if I just import if after bootstrap's import.

```
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'font-awesome';
```

I have done the above, but font-awesome's font is not overriding. I have pushed my project on github - https://github.com/murtaza52/rails-base. The url is accessible on localhost:3000/posts

I will appreciate if someone can help me overriding bootstraps's default font with those of font-awesome's

Comment: What order do the external CSS stylesheets appear in for your web page? (View source for a page to check.)

Comment: Its compiling everything into a single application.css. Inside application.css they are included in the order of bootstrap and then font awesome styles.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Modify your `application.css.scss` to look like below

```
@import "font-awesome";
$baseFontFamily: 'FontAwesome';
@import "bootstrap";

...

@import "bootstrap-responsive";
//@import "scaffolds";
@import "posts";
```

**WHY?**

1. You move `import "font-awesome"` at the top and then define `baseFontFamily` because that's what bootstrap uses to define `font-family` for all the elements. Check [Typography and links](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) block in the middle. If you `import bootstrap` after this, `FontAwesome` will be used by default.
2. You should remove `import "scaffolds";` line because `scaffolds.css.scss` will reset your font family for `body` element which will be inherited by every other element.

If you can't avoid importing it before bootstrap. I hope that helps.

Comment: This helped me get FontAwesome 4 (via the font-awesome-rails gem) to work with bootstrap-sass-rails. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For those of you guys using Bootstrap 3.2+ (I guess), here's the list of SASS variables you can modify:

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss

In our case, we want to make sure to define `$font-family-base` before doing `@import "bootstrap"`.

By setting `$font-family-base` before the line below is reached, Bootstrap uses our `$font-family-base` instead (otherwise, it defaults to `$font-family-base-serif`, also defined in the `variables.scss` above).

`$font-family-base:        $font-family-sans-serif !default;`

This is how my application.css.sass looks like

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

@import "fonts"
@import "compass"
@import "bootstrap"
```

And I have the following in `_fonts.css.sass` (You don't have to have it in a separate file)

`$font-family-sans-serif:  'Roboto', verdana, arial, sans-serif`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps you but at least sometimes when template code seems valid you need to force refresh your browser with ctrl+shirt+r to see changes (works at least in mozilla).